# WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0xC0000000 using winAPI

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm trying to create a window that I can display graphics on but within the message loop I am getting the "WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0xC0000000" error. As I understand it from other questions asked here it is due to the method trying to write to the wrong place.

The code is an adaption of what is found [here](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2008/02/26/python-gui-programming-platforms-for-windows/) but the message loop function has remained the same; I've even tried things like using PeekMessage and various other approaches.

```
from ctypes import *
import win32con

_WNDPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(c_long, c_int, c_uint, c_int, c_int)

_NULL = c_int(win32con.NULL)
_user32 = windll.user32
_gdi32 = windll.gdi32

def _ErrorIfZero(handle):
    if handle == 0:
        raise WinError()
    else:
        return handle

CreateWindowEx = _user32.CreateWindowExW
CreateWindowEx.argtypes = [c_int,
                           c_wchar_p,
                           c_wchar_p,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int,
                           c_int]
CreateWindowEx.restype = _ErrorIfZero

class _WNDCLASS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('style', c_uint),
                ('lpfnWndProc', _WNDPROC),
                ('cbClsExtra', c_int),
                ('cbWndExtra', c_int),
                ('hInstance', c_int),
                ('hIcon', c_int),
                ('hCursor', c_int),
                ('hbrBackground', c_int),
                ('lpszMenuName', c_wchar_p),
                ('lpszClassName', c_wchar_p)]

    def __init__(self,
                 wndProc,
                 style=win32con.CS_HREDRAW | win32con.CS_VREDRAW,
                 clsExtra=0,
                 wndExtra=0,
                 menuName=None,
                 className=u"PythonWin32",
                 instance=None,
                 icon=None,
                 cursor=None,
                 background=None,
                 ):

        if not instance:
            instance = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(c_int(win32con.NULL))
        if not icon:
            icon = _user32.LoadIconW(c_int(win32con.NULL),
                                     c_int(win32con.IDI_APPLICATION))
        if not cursor:
            cursor = _user32.LoadCursorW(c_int(win32con.NULL),
                                         c_int(win32con.IDC_ARROW))
        if not background:
            background = windll.gdi32.GetStockObject(c_int(win32con.WHITE_BRUSH))

        self.lpfnWndProc=wndProc
        self.style=style
        self.cbClsExtra=clsExtra
        self.cbWndExtra=wndExtra
        self.hInstance=instance
        self.hIcon=icon
        self.hCursor=cursor
        self.hbrBackground=background
        self.lpszMenuName=menuName
        self.lpszClassName=className

class _RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('left', c_long),
                ('top', c_long),
                ('right', c_long),
                ('bottom', c_long)]
    def __init__(self, left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0 ):
        self.left = left
        self.top = top
        self.right = right
        self.bottom = bottom

class _PAINTSTRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('hdc', c_int),
                ('fErase', c_int),
                ('rcPaint', _RECT),
                ('fRestore', c_int),
                ('fIncUpdate', c_int),
                ('rgbReserved', c_wchar * 32)]

class _POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_long),
                ('y', c_long)]
    def __init__( self, x=0, y=0 ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class _MSG(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('hwnd', c_int),
                ('message', c_uint),
                ('wParam', c_int),
                ('lParam', c_int),
                ('time', c_int),
                ('pt', _POINT)]

def RunMessageLoop():
    """Runs the loop to get messages from"""
    msg = _MSG()
    pMsg = pointer(msg)

    while _user32.GetMessageW(pMsg, _NULL, 0, 0):
        _user32.TranslateMessage(pMsg)
        _user32.DispatchMessageW(pMsg)

    return msg.wParam

## Lifted shamelessly from WCK (effbot)'s wckTkinter.bind
def EventHandler(message):
    """Decorator for event handlers"""
    def decorator(func):
        func.win32message = message
        return func
    return decorator

class Window(object):
    """The application window"""

    def __init__(self, title, updateHandler):

        #Store update function
        self.updateHandler = updateHandler

        #Register event handlers
        self._event_handlers = {}
        for key in dir(self):
            method = getattr(self, key)
            if hasattr(method, "win32message") and callable(method):
                self._event_handlers[method.win32message] = method

        #Register window class
        wndclass = _WNDCLASS(_WNDPROC(self.WndProc))
        wndclass.lpszClassName = u"HelloWindow"

        if not _user32.RegisterClassW(byref(wndclass)):
            raise WinError()

        #Now create the _Window

        self.Create( className=wndclass.lpszClassName,
                instance=wndclass.hInstance,
                windowName=title)

        #Show Window
        self.Show(win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        self.Update()

    def GetSize(self):
        rect = _RECT()
        _user32.GetClientRect(self.hwnd, byref(rect))
        return rect.width, rect.height

    def Create(self,
            exStyle=0 ,        #  DWORD dwExStyle
            className=u"WndClass",
            windowName=u"Window",
            style=win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            x=win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            y=win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            width=win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            height=win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            parent=_NULL,
            menu=_NULL,
            instance=_NULL,
            lparam=_NULL,
            ):

        self.hwnd = CreateWindowEx(exStyle,
                              className,
                              windowName,
                              style,
                              x,
                              y,
                              width,
                              height,
                              parent,
                              menu,
                              instance,
                              lparam)
        return self.hwnd

    def Show(self, flag):
        return _user32.ShowWindow(self.hwnd, flag)

    def Update(self):
        if not _user32.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd):
            raise WinError()

    def WndProc(self, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam):

        event_handler = self._event_handlers.get(message, None)
        if event_handler:
            return event_handler(message, wParam, lParam)
        return _user32.DefWindowProcW(c_int(hwnd),
                                      c_int(message),
                                      c_int(wParam),
                                      c_int(lParam))


    """Yipee Events :'( """

    @EventHandler(win32con.WM_PAINT)
    def OnPaint(self, message, wParam, lParam):
        """Window is updating so update graphics inside"""
        ps = _PAINTSTRUCT()
        hdc = _user32.BeginPaint(c_int(self.hwnd), byref(ps))

        self.updateHandler(hdc)

        _user32.EndPaint(c_int(self.hwnd), byref(ps))
        return 0

    @EventHandler(win32con.WM_DESTROY)
    def OnDestroy(self, message, wParam, lParam):
        """Quit app when window is destroyed"""
        _user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0

class DrawMethods:
    @staticmethod
    def DrawLine(handle, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        """Draw a line between points"""
        _gdi32.MoveToEx(c_int(handle),
                        x1,
                        y1,
                        NULL)
        _gdi32.LineTo(c_int(hdc),
                      x2,
                      y2)

    @staticmethod
    def DrawRect(handle, x, y, width, height):
        """Draw a rect at x and y of width and height"""
        _gdi32.Rectangle(c_int(handle),
                         x,
                         y,
                         x+width,
                         y+height)

    #@staticmethod
    #def DrawCircle(x, y, radius):

    @staticmethod
    def DrawText(handle, x, y, width, height, text):
        """Draw text at the specified coordinates"""                                    # UPDATE!!!!
        rect = _RECT(x, y, width, height)
        flags = win32con.DT_SINGLELINE|win32con.DT_CENTER|win32con.DT_VCENTER
        _user32.DrawTextW(c_int(handle),
                          text,
                          c_int(-1),
                          byref(rect),
                          flags)


class Test:
    """Create window and start message loop"""

    def __init__(self):
        #So create a window (yes this is multi window compatible I think) titled "TestWindow!" that calls the Update method to draw everything
        self.window = Window("Test Window!", self.Update)

    def Update(self, handle):
        """This is called when the window updates and you can then use the drawing functions available in Renderer.DrawMethods"""
        #Renderer omitted as in the same file
        DrawMethods.DrawText( handle, 0, 0, 500, 500, u"Helllloooo!!! Testy testy test test :D" )

t= Test()
RunMessageLoop()
```

I hope someone can help me, the code is designed to work on any windows machine so you should be able to run it (having said that the win32con import may be part of the pywin32 package...)

Thanks,

Jamie :)

Comment: Use the Windows types defined in `ctypes.wintypes`. It also defines `RECT`, `POINT`, `MSG` -- and correctly sizes `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` for 32-bit vs 64-bit Windows. Using `c_int` assumes 32-bit Windows. Also, to pass `NULL` as a parameter just use `None`.

Comment: OK I'll try that, thanks! They were like that in the source code so presumed they needed too be like that, do you think that will solve it?

Comment: It's just better style and would allow your script to run unmodified in a 64-bit process.

Comment: You should also look into `pywin32.win32gui` which already has definitions for `CreateWindowEx`, `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, and probably every other function you used with `ctypes`.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  See the Python for Windows Documentation that is installed with the `pywin32` extension.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Good point, but sometimes ctypes is used to avoid the pywin32 dependency. For the problem at hand, the solution posted below is fairly fragile.

Comment: As eryksun said, the plan was to try and not use any external modules if possible despite having seen that. All in all ctypes is proving quite limiting as I can't find any easy way of accessing the Graphics class in which supplies methods to give me further, valuable functionality... May start a new question but considering this was really only an experiment it's not too important. :) Thanks all!

Comment: @JamJar00, I saw your use of `win32con`, which is part of `pywin32` already, so you already have a 3rd party dependency :)

Comment: I know :P That was only temporary until I had finished and could then move the constants to my own file :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work... Seems the call to RunMessageLoop() needed to be within the Window class (at the bottom of the init routine).

Comment: You're not keeping a reference to `wndclass`, which references the `_WNDPROC` callback. So it gets deallocated when `__init__` returns.